# if $1=\int _{ 1 }^{ \infty }{ \frac { ax+b }{ x(2x+b) } dx } $ then $a+b=?$

Tags: calculus

I have the following question:

> if $1=\int _{ 1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { ax+b }{ x(2x+b) } dx } $ then $a+b=?$
>
> a) $0$
>
> b) $e$
>
> c) $2e-2$
>
> d) $1$

I tried finding it's anti-derivative but that doesn't seem to help.

I also tried to get it to $\int _{ 1 }^{ \infty  }{(\alpha-1) \frac { 1 }{ x^\alpha } dx } $ with $\alpha>1$   since that equals $1$ but without finding an answer.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: You tried finding the antiderivative. Did you succeed in finding the antiderivative?

Comment: you can try integration by parts.

Comment: yes: $1=\int _{ 1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ x } dx }+ \int _{ 1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { a-2 }{ 2x+b } dx }={ \left[ \ln { (x) }  \right]  }_{ 1 }^{ \infty  }+\frac { a }{ 2 } { \left[ \ln { (2x+b) }  \right]  }_{ 1 }^{ \infty  }-{ \left[ \ln { (2x+b) }  \right]  }_{ 1 }^{ \infty  }$

Comment: @anorton if you add the two you get the original integral. Is there anything wrong there?

Comment: @Paz Oops... never mind.  (didn't add correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, for the integral to converge, $a$ has to equal $0$ which implies

$$ 1=\int _{ 1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { b }{ x(2x+b) } dx }=\ln(b+2)-\ln(2)=\ln(\frac{b+2}{2}) $$

$$ \implies \frac{b+2}{2}=e \implies b=2 e -2 \implies a+b= 2 e-2 .$$

**Note:** Observe that, the integrand

$$ \frac { ax+b }{ x(2x+b) }\sim \frac{ax}{2x^2}=\frac{a}{2x}, $$

which is not integrable on $[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:** (1) If $a\ne 0$ what kind of trouble do we get into? (2) Partial fractions.